# groovy command line argument parsing

Tags: groovy, command-line

How can i safely parse command line arguments in groovy script.
Assuming i need atleast 1 value in command line but there could be multiple values which can also be supplied. do i need to check size of args[] everytime before accessing any argument

```
def local = ""
def date=""
if (args.size() == 1) {
    local = (String) this.args[0]
    date = this.args[1] // this will give me indexoutofbound if no second argument supplied
}
else {
    println "Incorrect parameters !!"
    System.exit(0)
}
```

i need a way to easily move through if value of "date" is not provided, i can do null check on date and work on it later in code.

Comment: `if (args.size() == 1)` then you have a `local` but no `date`, so set `date = null` in that case.. If `args.size() == 2` then you definitely have a date, so set `date = args[1]`.

Comment: @k314159 yes, that is i am doing , but can i do this variable assignment without checking size everytime. lets say if there are 5 arguments, i will have to check size each time.

Answer (score 1):

you have to ensure size before getting item from array

however you could use a shorter syntax

```
def local1 = args.size()>0 ? args[0] : null
def local2 = args.size()>1 ? args[1] : null
```

v2. list.getAt(i) returns null on missing index

```
def argList = args.toList()

def local1 = argList[0]  // [x] => getAt(x)
def local2 = argList[1]
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I have followed your mentioned solution. but i ran into one issue. lets say i have 5 arguments which can be passed to my script. now i want to pass 1st 2nd and 4th argument but not 3rd argument. how can i handle this scenario? I have a argument where i pass date in m/d/yyyy format. this is the third argument, if i pass NULL on place of date i get error, as code takes null as string.

Comment: implement logic to process special values `if(p=='NULL')...`. instead of NULL you could use `""` in command line which will be passed as empty string. or you could implement "named parameters" - every parameter must be prefixed with name: instead of `mycmd V1 V2 NULL V4` use something like `mycmd -p1 V1 -p2 V2 -p4 V4`. in groovy there is a special class that can do it: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.9/html/gapi/groovy/util/CliBuilder.html